# Is Naboo's core possible in real life?

Tags: planet, exoplanet, planetary-formation, core

In Star Wars, the planet Naboo has a plasma core, instead of a molten one.

Can a planet really have a plasma core?

Comment: Normal stars (not dead ones like white dwarfs or neutron stars) have plasma cores. But stars tend to be somewhat warmer than planets. ;)

Comment: Ok, I believe you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mass will pull into the shape of the sphere if the body is massive enough. The body will then basically be in hydrostatic equilibrium. A planet like Naboo couldn't exist b/c the denser materials would move to the centre, and the lighter elements would then form an atmosphere around the solid core.

Plasmas require really high temps and a terestrial plantet couldn't compress gases to the temps required to completely ionize the gas. That and what I said about the way the planet would form. There's just no way that a shell of rocky material could be supported by gas pressure in that way. The whole thing would be really unstable.

Comment: I don't think your last sentence is true - so long as the gas/fluid had a polytropic index of $n\sim 3$ (like the interior of Jupiter) it would be capable of supporting a "crust". How that could form is another matter. It is also unclear whether denser material would move to the centre (quickly) if convection is active.

Comment: Hi Rob, the bit about the stability? I see what you're saying, but a planet "like Naboo" would not be able to compress the gas/fluid into such an exotic state, eh?

I have a vague notion of polytropic indexs and what polytropes are, but I haven't taken a thermodynamics course (yet). Can you briefly expound on your  comment? I'm really curious to hear what you have to say. Thx.

Comment: Then just change your last two sentences which posit that gas pressure could not support a crust. It's more complicated than that. Certainly you can't easily have a density inversion, but gases can be denser than solids.